# Subtracting multiple rows from two sql queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created a betting database and I am trying to determine who are the best and worst betters. The easiest way I determined to do this is get the sum of the winnings by a user and subtract that by the sum amount they have bet

My first SQL query is

```
SELECT fromuser,SUM(itemsgiven::int)
FROM transactions
WHERE transtype='Bet Placed'
GROUP BY fromuser
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Which returns this

```
fromuser    sum
15228328    2689
13896406    2634
55954103    308
37460340    64
66589399    62
```

Then my second query is to determine the total winnings

```
SELECT touser,SUM(itemsgiven::float)
FROM transactions
WHERE transtype='Bet Won'
GROUP BY touser
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

which returns this

```
touser      sum
15228328    4387.515
55954103    152.295
13896406    120.285
66589399    71.28
37460340    56.925
```

My question is what is the best way to combine these queries so I can have a two columns, one with the user id and the other with their total winnings(or losings). I looked up some examples but the part that tripped me up is how do you make sure when you are subtracting the two sums that you only subtract from the same user id.

EDIT: I am using postgresql

Comment: Are you using mysql or postgres?  Please choose a platform, your answer may depend on functionality of one or the other.

Comment: I'm using postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this query:

```
SELECT usr, SUM(subtotal) AS total
FROM (
  SELECT   fromuser AS usr, SUM(itemsgiven::int) AS subtotal
  FROM     transactions
  WHERE    transtype='Bet Placed'
  GROUP BY fromuser

  UNION ALL

  SELECT   touser AS usr, -1*SUM(itemsgiven::float) AS subtotal
  FROM     transactions
  WHERE    transtype='Bet Won'
  GROUP BY touser
) s
GROUP BY usr
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

are you sure about itemsgiven::int and then itemsgiven::float?

Comment: This works just had to remove -1* from the second sum and move it to the first one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `UNION`:

```
 SELECT user_id, SUM(itemsgiven) as total_itemsgiven
 FROM
 (
   SELECT fromuser user_id, - itemsgiven::int itemsgiven
   FROM transactions
   WHERE 'Bet Placed' 
   UNION
   SELECT touser user_id, itemsgiven::int itemsgiven
   FROM transactions
   WHERE 'Bet Won'

 ) t
 GROUP BY user_id 
 ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: Nope sorry, that didn't seem to work. All it did was give me the results of my first sql query except with total being the negative result e.g. it gave me 15228328 and -2689

Comment: You cannot `GROUP BY touser` if `touser` is not in the `SELECT`

Comment: what are the fields in your transaction table? can you please add sample data to the question.

Comment: updated the code, as did not notice two user ids in transaction

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT fromuser as a,SUM(itemsgiven::numeric) as b
FROM transactions
WHERE transtype='Bet Placed'
GROUP BY fromuser
UNION 
SELECT touser as a,SUM(itemsgiven::numeric) as b
FROM transactions
WHERE transtype='Bet Won'
GROUP BY touser
) c
ORDER BY c.b DESC
```

Comment: This is close but it gives me both outputs of the tables in one table not the difference. e.g. [link](http://goo.gl/8aElCZ)

Comment: I changed UNION ALL with UNION